# Dotfuscator with UWP project(not Xamarin UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, decompiling, dotfuscator

I have seen that Dotfuscator is albe to use to Xamarin UWP. I have a normal UWP project(not Xamarin), can I use the  Dotfuscator ?  If a UWP without Dotfuscator, does third part people is easy to decompile and amend constant string(such as web url) in the code, and then get a amendment uwp application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Disclaimer*: I work for the Dotfuscator team and am answering this as part of my job.)

Yes, both the free Dotfuscator Community (formerly Dotfuscator CE) and the licensed Dotfuscator Professional can protect Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. I recommend using Dotfuscator Professional, for two reasons:

1. Professional's [build integration](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html) works much better with UWP than manually running Dotfuscator on the already-packaged `.appx` file. We are planning to bring this same integration into a future version of Dotfuscator Community.
2. [String encryption](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_obfuscation_string_encryption.html) (which protects constant strings) is a feature exclusive to Professional. After applying the build integration to your project, you can enable string encryption (and more protection features) by following [these directions](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_enhance.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can compile to native code if you don't use reflection.

Don't store secrets in source code. Store them separately so you can encrypt them, for example in a config file.